# Do [x% to find magic item] bonuses apply to my entire fellowship?

Tags: dungeon-siege-2

Description:

My Human character has a 10% bonus chance to find magic items. Does that mean that i have 10% increased chance to find phat lewt inside of chests/barrels/animals no matter what character i open it up with?

Example:

- Chance to drop "Item X" is 20% Human gets a 10% bonus to Find Magic
  Items. Human now has a 22% chance to find Item X

  Does the half-giant in my group have 20 or 22 percent chance of
  finding the same Item X when i open up a container while controlling him?

Answer (score 3):

The character with the biggest chance to find magic item applies for the whole party, so it doesnt matter who opens the container.